# How does Clickhouse sort data if primary / sorting key is number

Tags: clickhouse

I'm wondering how will Clickhouse sort data internally if I use number as primary key.
In [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/sparse-primary-indexes) they say:

> The inserted rows are stored on disk in lexicographical order
> (ascending) by the primary key columns

which would (maybe) imply that numbers are looked as strings and for example **10000** is lower / before **2**, but when looking at their examples in the same documentation link, when they sort by `UserID` field which is `UInt32`, it looks like data is actually sorted by numbers (and **not** their lexicographical representation) so row with `UserID` of value **240923** is before row with `UserID` of value **10487847**

My guess and expectation is that numbers (and other types like dates) are sorted as we would expect those types to be sorted so that `order by` clause later on can use primary / sorting key but I just wanted to double check.

Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted. I'm just wondering why do you need to know this other than the curiosity? What is your use case with the knowledge?

Comment: We have very specific use case where in some cases we want data to be sorted in certain way and we want to avoid changing our primary key and doing things like materialized views as it's too complicated. We have rows with correct "order" id already (smth like autoincrement) so wanted to use that for primary key to have ability to fetch it later on using same order (to use index for that). In general, in some cases I would have row ids (primary key) in ascending order: 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct: numbers are sorted by size, strings are sorted lexicographically...always ascending.